# Change the text colour of every row where a cell's value is 0?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently doing this:

```
    private void dgResults_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        // Would be nice if we could do this on databind of each row instead and avoid looping
        for (int r = 0; r < dgResults.Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            if (dgResults.Rows[r].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < dgResults.Rows[r].Cells.Count; c++)
                {
                    dgResults.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason it always misses out the first row. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the first row was selected.

```
    public TransparentDataGridView()
    {
        this.SelectionChanged += TransparentDataGridView_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void TransparentDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearSelection();
    }
```

Fixes it.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason it always misses out the first row

I don't know why (your code seems correct). If you want to avoid looping, you can use the `CellFormatting` event.

```
private void dgResults_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
    {
        dgResults.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason that makes it never return. Does setting the forecolor re-call the formatting event or something?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need an inner loop to set style for each cell in a row, rather you can use `DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor` property which will set style for entire row.

*try this code*

```
private void dgResults_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        // Would be nice if we could do this on databind of each row instead and avoid looping
        for (DataGridViewRow row in dgResults.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
               row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvc in dgResults.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(g => g.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "0"))
    {
        dgvc.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: How would that be any different? You are just looping through it a bunch more times (within the LINQ expressions)

Comment: @JoeNFU what do you mean by "But for some reason it always misses out the first row" do you mean that you have 0 in you Cell[5] in the first row but your above mentioned code nevertheless doesn't change the row color to white?

Comment: I have changed my Code as per @AccessDenied coding which is I think better than all and I have also checked your above mentioned code but in my case it does effect the first row if the condition is true;